# Is anything excecuted after using "return" in a function

Tags: php, sql

I appreciate that this is a pretty basic question but I just wanted to confirm something.

I've started working on a web application which has been previously worked on.

My understanding of return is that it immediately ends the excecution of the function. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

But from this understanding does,

```
return $myVariable;

sqlsrv_close($connection);
```

not close down the sql connection?

Again I appeciate this is PHP 101 but I just wanted to double check.

Comment: yes it will exit(return).

Comment: @tinybyte So the sql connection previously opened will not be closed down in this example?

Comment: @Shamrockonov: No, once you use return, your code will simply ignore what's after the "return" of the function itself. Therefore, in order to close the sql connection, you should do this before the return statement :) If you want to, just try to add an "echo 'something';" right after the return $myVariable;

Comment: @briosheje: much appreciated! upon further research it appears php will close off the connection once the script has ended anyway, but would it be better practice to , as you've said, put the close before the return?

Comment: @Shamrockonov: Yes, it is always better to close the connection right after you did what you needed to. In fact, in case of a long execution code (perhaps some code generating some external files ecc that may even take longer than 10-15 seconds), keeping the connection opened to the database is surely not the best solution :]

Comment: @briosheje Thank you so much! If I could just pick your brain one last time. I have a function that inserts records into multiple tables in a DB. At the moment, there are say 6 sqlsrv_query statements where the first query returns the new id created which is then inserted as an associative record in the other tables. Do I want to be closing and opening new connections for each statement? Or is it sufficient to just have one sqlsrv_close() at the end of the script and use sqlsrv_free_stmt() after each statement. I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible. Thanks Again

Comment: @Shamrockonov: I'm actually not a database master so, for a better hopinion, let's wait that some database expert read this. In any case, to me, I would rather execute all the queries I need to execute (I don't think they will take ages, unless you really have more than thousand and thousand of them at once) and then close the connection. I think, in fact, that opening and closing the connection for each query will just result in an useless polling that doesn't make things better :)

Comment: @briosheje I realised I'd gone off on a bit of a tangent as soon as I'd posted but that makes perfect sense. Can't thank you enough for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of return statement,

If called from within a function, the **return** statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.

So in your case it will not execute the code, `sqlsrv_close($connection);`

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

-oops- thought I was in the Java section.

But still, dead code.

Answer (score 0):

The "return" to end its execution immediately and pass control back to the line from which it was called

Hope this link help you more about return function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php